# Hive, Input path does not exist: hdfs://master:9000/user/hive/warehouse/_user_match_log_begin

Tags: mysql, import, hive, sqoop

I have trouble with Hive.

1. Completed this command. 
   sqoop import \
   --connection-manager org.apache.sqoop.manager.MySQLManager \
   --connect "" \
   --username root --password **** \
   --table _user_game_log \
   --m 1
2. Hive has a table.

## Detailed Table Information

Database:               default
Owner:                  ubuntu
CreateTime:             Wed Apr 18 03:45:09 UTC 2018
LastAccessTime:         UNKNOWN
Retention:              0
Location:               hdfs://master:9000/user/hive/warehouse/_user_match_log_begin
Table Type:             MANAGED_TABLE
Table Parameters:
    comment                 Imported by sqoop on 2018/04/18 03:44:55
    numFiles                1
    numRows                 0
    rawDataSize             0
    totalSize               195722
    transient_lastDdlTime   1524023111

When I send to hive,  select * from `_user_match_log_begin`;
It says 
"Failed with exception java.io.IOException:org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: hdfs://master:9000/user/hive/warehouse/_user_match_log_begin"

But hdfs://master:9000/user/hive/warehouse/_user_match_log_begin already exists. 
I found out that underscore in path '_user...' is reason.

How can I solve it using underscore...?

Comment: Hive has an issue while parsing table start with _ I would suggest removing _ before hive table name to solve this issue.

Comment: The problem was hive table location. I remove _ in hdfs path and change hive table location as changed hdfs path as well. That works. 
But do you know how to change hdfs path and table location path when importing hive using scoop? It just work as what Mysql table name is.